# Maven archetype generate with custom properties

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-archetype

Newbie question here, I have a maven archetype that I'm creating from a java project using a .properties file. I want to be able to generate dynamic values for variables within the archetype and I'm not sure how to do that. Currently I'm following [this maven guide](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/create-with-property-file.html) and but I can't seem to reproduce what they've done. Specifically at the bottom of the guide where they replace the String value with a new value.

Here's the properties file I'm using:

```
archetype.groupId=com.mycompany
archetype.artifactId=sample-project
archetype.version=1.0

archetype.languages=java

myParam=something
```

I checked my archetype-metadata.xml file and the properties I'm trying to load are in there:

```
<requiredProperty key="myParam">
  <defaultValue>new value here</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

However, none of my classes have the new value loaded. Is there a step that I'm missing that replaces the default value of the parameter and replaces it with the new value specified in the prop file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably right, there is not any fragment how a `App.java` or others class look likes after creating archetype and before creating a project.

Assuming you dont know how to use your custom properties, and your final `App.java` class need to look like this (just an example):

```
package my.new.group;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App
{
    String value = "something";
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

And your `archetype.properties` file looks like this you pasted, your Archetype `App.java` class (before installing archetype!) need to look like this:

```
package ${archetype.groupId};

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class ${archetype.artifactId}
{
    String value = "${myParam}";
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

if you got prepared file like this, you can easly `mvn install` this archetype

then if u create project you will be ask to confirm a values from properties file. And thats all. Value from archetype.properties should be applied